# Virtual keyboard doesn't appear on first touch

Tags: android

I have an `EditText`, for which I want to change the text style when it is focused and it's content is equal to a default content. Here is the code snippet:

```
input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (input.getText().toString().equals(defaultText)) {
                input.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.contact_us_info_header);
                input.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The issue is that the virtual keyboard doesn't show up when I touch this `EditText` the 1st time (the text cursor does appear inside the `EditText`), but it show up the keyboard when I touch it one more time. If I remove this line:

```
input.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.contact_us_info_header);
```

then the keyboard shows up right the first time when I touch the `EditText`.
Is there anyway to make the keyboard show up on first touch without removing the above line of code?

Any help will appreciated.

P/S: I used it inside a fragment, that's why I need to call "getActivity()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a shot

```
input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                   v.performClick();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

and

```
input.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (input.getText().toString().equals(defaultText)) {
                        input.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.contact_us_info_header);
                        input.setText("");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
input.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.contact_us_info_header);
```

try:

```
input.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.contact_us_info_header);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I used it inside a fragment, so call to "this" is not applicable :(